# How can I modify a web page using (IE )DOM to add Form Elements and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I have 3rd party application (compiled) that can read data from an HTML page. This is done by creating an Internet Explorer object and loading an empty page (.navigate "about:blank"). Form element are added to the page via Document.Body.innerHTML. When exiting the HTML page via Submit the application reads the submission data via CreateObject("WScript.Shell"). I would like to add some JavaScript to combine input data in to a string. That is, data input into input text box 1 and input text box 2 are joined in text box 3 OR/AND change the values in textbox 3 based on check boxes or radio buttons. I could then send these values back to the application. How can I further modify this empty web page to include java script to accomplish the above

The "g_objIE.Document.Body.innerHTML = " code works just fine. It is very basic and just includes form elements. Can I simply add java script to innerHTML? I don't think so.  I tried adding very basic code and received a 'expecting end of statement' error. I was attempting to insert:
"

" & _ " document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 5 + 6; "& _

This is the working code.

```
' First step, set up the dialog (InternetExplorer)
Set g_objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
g_objIE.Offline = True
g_objIE.navigate "about:blank"
g_objIE.document.focus()

' Wait for the navigation to the "blank" web page to complete
Do
    crt.Sleep 900
Loop While g_objIE.Busy

g_objIE.Document.body.Style.FontFamily = "Sans-Serif"

' Here's where we "create" the elements of our dialog box.  We basically
' throw HTML into the document, and IE loads it in real-time for us.
' 
' The hidden "ButtonHandler" input is used to tie IE and
' SecureCRT together such that SecureCRT can know when a
' button is pressed, etc.

g_objIE.Document.Body.innerHTML = _
  "<input type=radio name='LogMode' value='Append' AccessKey='A' checked>fpeth.3125 / Access" & _
    "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;" & _
        "<input type=radio name='LogMode' value='Overwrite' Accesskey='w' >fpeth.3070 / Core<br>" & _
    "<hr>" & _
    "<b>Path/File</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name='fName' size='60' maxlength='60' tabindex=1><br>" & _
    "<b>HOST</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name='tID' size='30' maxlength='30'><br>" & _

    "<hr>" & _
    "<button name='Cancel' AccessKey='C' onclick=document.all('ButtonHandler').value='Cancel';><u>C</u>ancel</button>" & _
    "<input name='ButtonHandler' type='hidden' value='Nothing Clicked Yet'>"

g_objIE.MenuBar = False
g_objIE.StatusBar = True
g_objIE.AddressBar = False
g_objIE.Toolbar = False
g_objIE.height = 270
g_objIE.width = 510   
g_objIE.document.Title = "TCP"
g_objIE.Visible = True
```

Comment: *"...3rd party application (compiled)"* Please post the pre-/un-compiled application. ATM this OP looks like a mangled mess.

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll want to control the HTML header and doctype of your document, which means you'll need to use `document.write` instead of `body.innerHTML`. As well as making scripts work, this will give you control of the HTML head and doctypes.
2. To make things easier to maintain, use a variable to hold your HTML string

```
Dim htmlString
htmlString = _
  "<!doctype html>" & _
  "<html>" & _
  "<head><title>tcp</title></head>" & _
  "<body>" & _
  "<input type=radio name='LogMode' value='Append' AccessKey='A' checked>fpeth.3125 / Access" & _
    "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;" & _
        "<input type=radio name='LogMode' value='Overwrite' Accesskey='w' >fpeth.3070 / Core<br>" & _
    "<hr>" & _
    "<b>Path/File</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name='fName' size='60' maxlength='60' tabindex=1><br>" & _
    "<b>HOST</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name='tID' size='30' maxlength='30'><br>" & _
    "<hr>" & _
    "<button name='Cancel' AccessKey='C' onclick=document.all('ButtonHandler').value='Cancel';><u>C</u>ancel</button>" & _
    "<input name='ButtonHandler' type='hidden' value='Nothing Clicked Yet'>" & _
    "<div id=demo>goes here</div>" & _
    "<script> " & _
    "   document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (5 + 6).toString(); " & _
    "</script>" & _
    "</body>" & _
    "</html>"

g_objIE.document.write(htmlString)
```